# Spring, Spring-security : Spring-security returning 302, even if login failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Spring-security for authentication and authorization. I am connecting to the webapp via Android using RestTemplate.

Currently, the problem I am having is that even if Login fails, i am receiving 302 instead of 200. Because of that, on the client-side I don't know that login has failed. After which when the user tries to access secured-resource, access is denied and the app dies.

Can anyone tell me how to return correct response-code when there is a Login failure and how to detect it via Response code. Thanks a lot.

securityApplicationContext.xml :

```
 <security:http pattern="/resources/template/demo/clients" security="none"/>

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/dashboard"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/sessionexpired"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

On Android side, here is how I am doing authentication :

```
    private class LoginUserViaRest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            final EditText userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
            final EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordField);

            rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = rest.execute(StaticRestTemplate.baseURL+"j_spring_security_check", HttpMethod.POST,
                    new RequestCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                            request.getBody().write(("j_username=" + userEmail.getText().toString() + "&j_password=" + userPassword.getText().toString()).getBytes());
                        }
                    }, new ResponseExtractor<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
// Here I can get the code to determine if login was successful
                            List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Cookie");
                            if (cookies == null) {
                                cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
                            }
                            String cookie = cookies.get(cookies.size() - 1);
                            int start = cookie.indexOf('=');
                            int end = cookie.indexOf(';');

                            return cookie.substring(start + 1, end);
                        }
                    });
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

If there is any further explanation necessary, kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Update*

Login.jsp :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <div class="container-fluid white-div">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <h2><spring:message code="login.title"/></h2>
                <form id="login-form" class="login-page" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><spring:message code="login.label.email"/> <span id="eMailError" class="red-font"></span></label>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input type="email" name="j_username" id="j_username" value="" class="form-control input" placeholder="<spring:message code="common.input.email.placeholder"/>">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><spring:message code="login.label.password"/> <span id="passwordError" class="red-font"></span></label>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"  class="form-control input"  placeholder="<spring:message code="login.password.placeholder"/>">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label class="pull-left" for="show-password">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-password"><spring:message code="common.label.showpassword"/>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="forgotpassword pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#passwordForgotModal"><spring:message code="login.forgotpassword"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"><spring:message code="login.submit"/></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span><spring:message code="login.registration.text"/> <a href="/registration" class="forgotpassword"><spring:message code="login.registration.link"/></a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div> -->
        <c:if test="${not empty url}">
            <%-- <a href="${url}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block si-facebook si-colored verticalAlignCenter"><spring:message code="common.facebook"/></a> --%>
        </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ofcourse you will get a 302 as that is what the login filter does, it redirects to the initially requested URL. If you don't want that don't use the form login .

Comment: @M.Deinum : Which URL then should I target with Rest?

Comment: You will have to create something for that...

Comment: @M.Deinum : Oh!!. Any links you have which have any example or similar thing? I don't know where to start. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I have a login.jsp sir, where I am passing username and password to Spring-security. Can you help me understand how to integrate that with Spring-Security. I am updating my main post to include its contents. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`security:form-login` is designed for web apps rather than REST clients. Although you can use it, you'll run into the kind of trouble you've described here.

I recommend using `security:http-basic` instead (secured over HTTPS) and sending the login details each time.

Edit: If you insist on using form login, you'll need to tell the `RestTemplate` not to follow redirects, which you can do with the following (using Apache HttpComponents instead of the standard JRE `HttpUrlConnection`):

```
    final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(
            new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    ).build();
    factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

Comment: As I understood, I have to add <http-basic/> in the securityApplicationContext.xml I have posted and send username/password with every request. My current infrastructure just sends JSESSIONID and that is right now enough, and I intend to maintain it that way. Is it possible to send JSESSOINID instead of username&pass for every request to access secured resource. Or, I just want to know that login has failed, so I can display a message and user can try again(Larger goal). Kindly let know. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Also, this won't help because I would get  a 401 if the request fails and again the REST android app I have will die, not serving the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the updated. Will I be able to use status codes after the modification you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, the status code of 302 will be available in the response

Comment: @artbristol however, is it possible to use session based authorizartion (only first request by credintals) ?

Comment: @HaskellFun yes but you should ask a separate question for that